# Joomla redirect query string with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

How to redirect https://www.themaidsofcharleston.com/?Itemid= to https://www.themaidsofcharleston.com/

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^?Itemid=$
RewriteRule ^/$  /?  [R=301,L]
```

but id doesn't work

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `{QUERY_STRING}` does not contain the leading question mark - you want to check for `^Itemid=$`

Comment: Fixed the query string, redirect still not working

Comment: When configuring rewriting in .htaccess context, the path never starts with a `/`, that has been stripped off at that point already. So your rule needs to match an empty path instead, `^$`

Comment: That WORKS. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues needed fixing here:

- `{QUERY_STRING}` does not contain the leading question mark - you want to check for `^Itemid=$`
- when configuring rewriting in .htaccess context, the path never starts with a `/`, that has been stripped off at that point already. So your rule needs to match an empty path instead, `^$`